# Encryption question

Tags: encryption

Using Ubuntu 14.04LTS.
Home directory is encrypted.
Dropbox is in 'home' directory.
Therefore, is Dropbox encrypted?

Or, should Dropbox's method of encryption be used?

Also, if files from 'home' directory are stored in other clouds, are they encrypted?

Comment: not related to your case and just want to be helpful. but if you want to use google drive you can use "grive" software

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox itself does not encrypt the local cache of your dropbox files on your desktop PC - these are stored in a regular folder.  So dropbox's own encryption would only involve what's sent over the network and/or stored on their servers.

In the case of Ubuntu using home directory encryption, per-user data for virtually all apps will be stored within the user's home directory and benefit from the same encryption.

That is, it will not be any more secure than the existing home directory encryption that Ubuntu uses.

Answer (score 0):

Files are only encrypted on the disk that has encryption. Encryption is a file system feature. Copy a file over to a non-encrypted system the file is not encrypted.

> are stored in other clouds, are they encrypted?

Only if the cloud itself is encrypted. So that is separate from your /home encryption.

If you want files to be protected from casual viewing on what system they are you could protect them with a password after archiving the file.

Comment: Given that ecryptfs is used and "Dropbox" inside the encrypted home just behaves like a usual folder or file shouldn't this also pass through ecryptfs and be de- or encrypted on the fly? May be I got the encrypted home setup or something else wrong, I only use ecrpytfs with `mount`.